# How to access the related model without performing query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here's what I am doing now:

```
Class Book{
    ....
    public int authorID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AuthorID")]
    public virtual Author author { get; set; }

}
```

From a function where I get `Book` as input. In order to retrieve the author properties, I will have to call a query on `Author` by `book.authorID` even though I have `Author` as a property of `Book`.

```
public string getAuthor (int bookID){
    Book book = _db.Book.where(b => b.id == bookID).SingleOrDefault();
    int authorID = book.authorID;
    Author author = _db.Author.where(a => a.authorID == booking.authorID).SingleOrDefault();
    return author.name;
}
```

But I found this code unreasonably lengthy and I suspect there must be something that I missed so that I could not retrieve `Author` directly from the *book* instance like:

```
public string getAuthor (int bookID){
    Book book = _db.Book.where(b => b.id == bookID).singleOrDefault();
    // anyway to get book.author popuplated by this query?
    return book.author.name;
    //not working. book.author is null 
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: How do you expect to get data without querying the database?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your quick response. let me change the example code a little bit so that I will query the db once.

Comment: By the way, your code really should be more complete. What you've posted isn't what you actually have. For example `singleOrDefault` should be `SingleOrDefault` and what is `booking.authorID`?

Comment: @DavidG, it's compiled and the former example does work. I just needed to simplify it from thousands of unrelated codes and change the variable names to less sensitive ones. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Well it maybe works now you've fixed the code. But still, what is `booking.authorID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to retrieve the author properties, I will have to call a query on Author by booking.authorID even though I have `Author` as a property of `Book`.

No, you don't have that. You're in an API call, given the `[FromBody]` attribute. Every API call starts without any context of the previous one.

There's three possibilities:

1. You trust the client to provide `Book.Author` in their POST request. But you don't, because we never trust user input.
2. You query the information from the database, using the `Book.Id` input you receive in the POST request.
3. You cache the data somehow, and first try to obtain the relevant information from the cache, and if that fails, do #2 again.

That being said, a book can have multiple authors.

Comment: hi codecaster, thanks for your quick response. I changed the sample code so that I query the book by ID once. So it matches your scenario#2. Do you think author will be populated from that query?

Comment: No, because you don't `Include()` it, but that's a different question altogether. See [EF Core Docs: Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). It also really helps if you let your question contain your actual, compiling code.

Comment: Oh man, i think you got it. Include() should be the guy I am looking for. Let me test it out. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, since `Author` is virtual, assuming you're using EF Core 2.1+, `Author` will be loaded automatically the first time you attempt to access it. It's still preferable to eagerly load it via `Include` though.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisPratt. 2.0 actually, still trying to learn a lot. Do you think do you mean THE `Author` by the `authorID` or just the `Author` model in general? I guess the former one.

Comment: @DBSQUARED 2.0 doesn't have lazy loading, you need to use `Include`

Comment: EF Core 2.1 supports lazy-loading now. So when you attempt to access the `Author` property, EF will automatically issue a query for the author and load in the data. This assumes your property is virtual, though, since the lazy-loading logic is added via overriding the property on a derived proxy class in-memory and a property cannot be overridden unless it's virtual. However, if you're still using 2.0, which does not support lazy-loading, then the virtual keyword does nothing and is unnecessary.